# load sub node in tree grid

Tags: extjs5, treegrid

I have tree grid. It has own Store which on item expand sends id and loads node values from server. now I want to add node in database and reload sub node and not all tree.
I got node using this function

```
var node = tree.getStore().getNodeById('69');
```

Now I want to simple say "node.load()". is it possible? 
how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
 tree.getStore().load({node: node});
```